# Windows 10 shuts down instead of going to sleep

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Windows 10 shuts down instead of going to sleep.
So i loose every opened applications.

I tried the troubleshout. But there is no errors detected.

I also tried with hibernate mode, but still the same result.

Idk what to do.

Any clue ?

thanks.

ps: ask me if you need specific informations.

Comment: Update the Power Driver, possibly even BIOS, reset the Power settings to default, final restart and test.

Comment: Run `powercfg -energy -output report.html` in an elevated command prompt, then post online the HTML file for us to examine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See (by searching is *Settings*) *View Reliability History* or *Problem Reports*. Both will show you the same error report. Post it here.